# How to add combined columns in linq where clause?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My query is like this:

```
var list = context.Items
  .Where(i => i.Title.StartsWith(searchValue) || 
             (i.Title + string.format("{0}prep", i.OrderNumber))
                .StartsWith(searchValue))
  .ToList();
```

But I am gettings exception - object not set to the instance of the object.
I also tried to add `.AsEnumerable` after `.Where` but doesn't work.

Without `AsEnumerable` I am getting:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression.

What I did wrong here?

Comment: string.format("{0}prep")) ?! This code doesn't compile. Please paste your actual code.

Comment: Something is null... Either `context` or `context.Items` are `null` or `Items` contains null for some values and throws when you try to access members of an item in predicate like `i.Title...` when `i` is null.

Comment: Nothing is null. I check database and all values exist. I also updated question with another exception when AsEnumerable is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I did wrong here?

The answer is in the exception message:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

In other words, `string.Format` method is not supported because it cannot be translated to SQL query.

Fortunately string concatenation is supported, so you can use this instead:

```
var list = context.Items.Where(i => i.Title.StartsWith(searchValue)
    || (i.Title + i.OrderNumber + "prep").StartsWith(searchValue))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. If it's not a problem for small sub question. If I want to use i.OrderNumber..ToString("D2") why this is not possible in query like this?

Comment: For the same reason. "D2" is a .NET framework format, as well as `int.ToString` method accepting string formats. I can't say if it's 100% technically impossible to try to map it to some database function, but the EF designers decided to not do that. Normally if you need formatting the results, you simple use `AsEnumerable` and do that in LINQ to Objects which supports all framework methods, but for `Where` it's tricky because it will bring all the data in memory before filtering it. [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681(v=vs.110).aspx) contains info what is supported.